# How to hide the first element with a class name

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have twp elements inside my Div,both have same class name. I want to hide my first element with the class name `.cart`. I am using the below code.

```css
.component-bottom  .component-basket + .cart{
     display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="component-bottom">
  <div class="component-basket">
    <div class="cart">
    </div>
    <div class="cart">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I using the correct code?

Comment: Example of how to use [http://jsfiddle.net/bGLxJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/bGLxJ/)

Comment: I don't think that's the right code based on your description, but you really should just show us your markup.

Comment: @Vucko : Maybe the first instance of `cart` only? http://jsfiddle.net/bGLxJ/1/

Comment: As bolt said, we need your markup, without markup, it will be like killing a deer with eyes closed..

Comment: `.component-basket .basket:first-child{ display: none; }`

Comment: @AldiUnanto, that assumes .basket is the first child. We don't know that without markup.

Comment: @jrConway yep. so for questioner, let us know your html tag

Comment: @jrConway  I have added the html markup..thank you

Comment: @Vucko  I have added the html markup..thank you

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn  I have added the html markup..thank you

Comment: @rightPath my first comment should work. `.component-basket .basket:first-child{ display: none; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a direct child selector for the `.cart` element:

```
.component-bottom .component-basket > .cart
{
     display:none;
}
```

Now you only want the first element of this selector. There isn't an original selector for this, but you can make a overwrite selector for this. 
You can overwrite **all but the first one** `ElementA ~ ElementB`:

```
.component-bottom .component-basket > .cart ~ .cart
{
    display:block;
}
```

This search for all `.cart` elements inside `.component-basket` where **ANY** previous adjacent sibling is `.cart`. The first of the element doesn't have a previous sibling of this class, so it would not be selected.

This is called a [general sibling selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector).

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BTF39/1)

This should support IE7 and above:

> Note  Requires Windows Internet Explorer 7 or later.

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358824(v=vs.85).aspx

---

an easier solution commented by @jrConway:

Make it display: block by default and use:

```
.component-bottom .component-basket > .cart:first-child
{
     display: none;
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BTF39/3/)**

*Note that this only work when you use ONLY `.cart` as child element. Whenever an other class is at the first 'place' it will not work.*

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to do the opposite? Make it display: block by default and use .component-bottom .component-basket > .cart:first-child. Admittedly, though, I've been working with CSS for years and never knew the sibling selector even existed.

Comment: I completely agree. It's far more easy. But this would only work if it only contains `.cart` elements. I have no idea if he intend to add other classes to a child. With the selectors i used you can define a class by first element, even when it isn't the first child. But you're right, it's easier for the example the OP showed. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: Someone else mentioned it in a comment on the question before I brought it up. But thanks for the reply. ^^

Comment: @nkmol your answer works well..I selected the first one because it supports ie7 and ie8..thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Using adjacent sibling selector won't work here, as your element is nested inside `.component-basket` and hence it fails.. Simple way is to call a `class` on the element you want to hide, if you cannot change the DOM than you can use `first-child` or `nth-of-type(1)`

```
.component-bottom .component-basket div.cart:nth-of-type(1) {
     display:none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vq9Qw/)

---

> As [@Vucko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186810/adjacent-sibling-selector-css/20187201#comment30096829_20187201) already commented, [`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) is a CSS3 spec pseudo..
>   Hence if you want to [support](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3) legacy browsers, you can use [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/),
>   this will save you a lot of classes/ids.

Comment: @rightPath `nth-of-type` is a **CSS3 selector** which doesn't work in IE8 or less.

Comment: @rightPath no, if you want to do that than a very straight forward way is to add a class on the element you want to hide, if you cannot, than you can also go with nkmols solution, also, if you are looking to support legacy browsers, than you can save hell lot of your css by using polyfills available, like if you want to make this work, you can use http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: @Vucko thanks for posting that out, actually I do that often but I missed it this time

Answer (score 0):

As understood, check this might help

CSS

```
.cart{
    display:none;
}

.component-bottom  .component-basket
{
    //some common properties
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="component-bottom">
    <div class="component-basket cart">component-basket Hidden div</div>
    <div class="component-basket">component-basket visible div</div>
</div>
```

This will hide the div with the cart class (the First div)

Thanks,

Dhiraj

Answer (score 0):

Stick this in your CSS file:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Then add that class to whatever element you want hidden like so:

```
<div class="component-bottom">
    <div class="component-basket">Foo</div>
    <div class="component-basket cart hide">Foo</div>
</div>
```

The advantage of this method is that you get to re-use that "hide" class anywhere you want.

Comment: That'll work, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the op can do this. Its very possible that this is a shopping cart script of some sort, so all the markup is pre-rendered. Plus its annoying having to add classes all the time; the beauty of CSS is the ability to change how the page looks without having to constantly change the markup.

Comment: @jrConway A core tenant of CSS is reusability. A .hide class that is available site-wide can be quite handy. There is almost always more than one way to do something with CSS, and the "best" way depends on the situation. Armed with the different methods, the implementor can decide what will work best for their situation.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I also always hear complaints about how the less HTML markup needed the better. That's why over the past year I've been trying to switch to using more descriptive classes about what the markup is intended to actually do, as opposed to what it should look like. Still, in some circumstances it may be needed, as you say, it all depends.